Using module xattr in Python 3 on Mac
Core question: How can I read a file's content creation date with the library xattr in Python on a MacBook Pro?
Full explanation: I see the attributes Created, Modified and Content created for a file in Finder. The attributes Created and Modified show the same date, the attribute Content created shows another date. I have not yet found a python argument which is able to return the Content created date.
In the code below, the arguments os.stat / st_birthtime and os.path.getmtime return the same date as Created and Modified. The argument os.path.getctime returns a date which differs from Created, Modified and Content created.
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import xattr, os, time

file = 'myimage.jpg'

# Retrieving & printing general file statistics (e.g., creation time, modification time, etc.)
file_stats = os.stat(file)
print(f"> [01] File created (st_birthtime): {time.ctime(file_stats.st_birthtime)}")
print(f"> [02] File created (os.path.getctime): {time.ctime(os.path.getctime(file))}")
print(f"> [03] File last modified (os.path.getmtime): {time.ctime(os.path.getmtime(file))}")

# Try to read extended attributes with xattr
attributes = None
try:
    # Attempting to read the extended attributes of the file
    attributes = xattr.xattr(file)
    print(f"> [04] Extended attributes are found")  # If successful, printing that extended attributes were found
except OSError as e:
    print(f"> [05] Error retrieving extended attributes: {e}")  # If an error occurs, printing the error message

# Checking if no extended attributes were retrieved
if attributes is None:
    print(f"> [06] 'attributes' is 'None'")
else:
    print(f"> [07] 'attributes' is not 'None'")
    # Checking if there are any attributes inside 'attributes'
    if len(attributes) > 0:
        try:
            # Trying to get the 'kMDItemFSCreationDate' attribute
            creation_date_raw = attributes.get(b'com.apple.metadata:kMDItemFSCreationDate')
            timestamp = struct.unpack('d', creation_date_raw)[0]  # 'd' is for double precision float
            # Print the timestamp as a human-readable date, same as time.ctime()
            print(f"> [08] Content created on (Finder): {time.ctime(timestamp)}")
        except KeyError:  # If the attribute does not exist, catching the KeyError
            print(f"> [09] The attribute 'com.apple.metadata:kMDItemFSCreationDate' does not exist for this file")
        except OSError as e: # If an error occurs while retrieving the attribute
            print(f"> [10] Error retrieving the creation date: {e}")
    else:
        print(f"> [11] No extended attributes found") # If no extended attributes are found, printing that no attributes exist

Help pages suggest that the combination of
A = xattr.xattr(file)
B = A.get(b'com.apple.metadata:kMDItemFSCreationDate')

should return the date as received for Content created. However, I end up with errors. Specifically, the following comment lines are returned:
> [01] File created (st_birthtime): 1191188948.0
> [02] File created (os.path.getctime): 1735311582.31419
> [03] File last modified (os.path.getmtime): 1191188948.0
> [04] Extended attributes are found
> [07] 'attributes' is not 'None'
> [11] No extended attributes found

How can I read a file's content creation date with the library xattr in Python on a MacBook Pro? As visible from the results, the arguments st_birthtime, os.path.getctime and os.path.getmtime are no proper workarounds.
Technical parameters:

MacOS Sequoia Version 15.1.1 (24B91)
Python Version 3.11.8
Library attr Version 1.1.0

